# access to a web application from ubuntu 14.04 to windows 7

Tags: 14.04, apache2, webapps

I have two machines in my networks business, windows and other ubuntu 14.04 which I install apache on it, from my windows machine, I want to access to a web application on the ubuntu machines, I type the ip machine ubuntu in my browser (10.1.1.177/myapp) but its not working, anyone have any idea?

Comment: Check routing, firewall, apache logs, system logs and post the actual error. "It's not working" is not an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the IP Address you have **10.1.1.177** is private, it means that, this can only be recognized and accessible within the same domain not from the PC which is not part of your home network.

So for accessing your PC from any remote site, you have to determine your Public IP address, that is, your Router's IP Address, then you have to forward your port number (which is **80** in your case, but it might be different if you manually select some other port number). For understanding of port forwarding and router's working, the links below maybe helpful:

[How To Forward Ports on Your Router](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/)

[How to Set Up Port Forwarding on a Router](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router)